# strapi POST file to /upload with relation to a model fails

Tags: strapi

Doing a POST to http://localhost:1337/upload with the following JSON data and with enough permissions to upload.

The file uploaded is related to an existing entity of model 'product'

```
{
 "files":"@/path/to/file/image1.png",
 "refId":"5bed7b1f7eb8792e4737dc3f",
 "ref":"product",
 "field":"image"
}
```

But fails with the following error in strapi error log:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `refId` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

and with  500 "Internal Server Error" response.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a FormData

The example bellow is to upload a file, you will have to add your `ref` attributes to make it work with relations.

```
  <form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var data = new FormData();
      $.each($('#files')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('files', file);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jim. Posting as a form-data works.

Comment: I dont see any ref attribute mentioned in the actual code of the answer...